# Issue running a python script in shell script that has spaces to the python script

Tags: shell-script, escape-characters

I am doing some automation with shell scripting and I am having trouble running a python script in which its' path has spaces. Forgive me if I made any mistakes or bad practices in the code, I just started learning yesterday :).

Here is the code:

```
# grabs root directory from the script path
script_path="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; pwd -P )"
proj_root="${script_path///modelsim}"
proj_root="${proj_root///test}"

# removing spaces
proj_root_no_spaces="${proj_root/' '/'\ '}"

log_dir=${proj_root_no_spaces}/src/python/graph_log.py #path to python file relative to root project dir

# checking output
echo "$log_dir"
create_graphs="python3 \""$log_dir"\""
echo "$create_graphs"

# run command
$create_graphs
```

This script gives this output:

```
1) /mnt/c/Users/Varun\ Govind/Desktop/roulette_BACKUP/roulette/src/python/graph_log.py 
2) python3 "/mnt/c/Users/Varun\ Govind/Desktop/roulette_BACKUP/roulette/src/python/graph_log.py"
3) python3: can't open file '"/mnt/c/Users/Varun\': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The first line is the full path to the python file, you can see that there is a space in between my user name so I escaped it with a backslash. The second line is the full python command that I am running; in addition to escaping the space, I've surrounded the path with double-quotes. If I run that however, I get an error on line 3.

If I copy and paste line 2 directly into my shell, and run it, it works. I'm not sure why my command isn't working in my shell script. Is there something wrong with how I am escaping the spaces or running the python command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Long answer: Don't try to embed shell syntax (like quotes and escapes) in variables; variables are for data, not syntax. Instead, just put double-quotes around variable references (i.e. put the quotes *around* the variable, not *in* the variable). For the same reason, don't try to store commands in variables, just execute them directly.

Thus, skip `proj_root_no_spaces` and just store the path, unescaped spaces and all:

```
log_dir=${proj_root}/src/python/graph_log.py #path to python file relative to root project dir
```

Then don't store the `python3 ...` command in `create_graphs`, just execute it directly:

```
python3 "$log_dir"
```